# How can I play an online sound clip on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, audio-player

I'm trying to create an application to play short sound clips that are found online. I can't put them on the client so they need to be played from the internet. I am able to play sounds using a MediaElement but only when the sound clip is found on the phone. How can I make it download an play a sound clip from the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaElement can be used for this. You should use the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.source%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Media" Source="http://www.domain.com/song"/>
```

You can set the source from code as well

```
Media.Source = new Uri("http://www.domain.com/song");
Media.Play();
```

Comment: It tells me that a Uri needs to be a local resource.

Comment: Are you maybe missing a capability for your app? (WMAppManifest.xml). Are you using the Relative UriKind? Leave out the second parameter for the Uri ctor or use UriKind.Absolute

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem was but I got it working now! thanks for the help!